# How do I use command line and install packages with pip?

Tags: python, pip, command, line

I'm trying to install the pyenchant package so that I can have an English dictionary in python. How do I install the package?

I've downloaded the package to my computer and tried to use

```
pip install pyenchant
```

which gave me an "invalid syntax" error for "install." I then did more research and learned that you are supposed to use the command line, which is done on a Mac by starting a line with $. I then tried

```
$ pip install pyenchant
```

and got an "invalid syntax" error for "$". When I tried

```
pip --version
```

to see if I had pip at all (although I should since I have Python 3.7), it said "name 'version' is not defined." How do I install the package?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: char `$` is not part of command but only information that it has to be used in command line, not Python's shell - run `pip install pyenchant` in console/terminal/cmd.exe. And you don't have to download it - `pip` should download it automatically. Or you have to use `pip install path/to/downloaded/file`. When you run command line then it display `$` as prompt to inform user that now it can write command.

Comment: you can also use `python -m pip install pyenchant` in command line (console/terminal/cmd.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you typing these commands into the Python interpreter? If so, try this instead:

1. click the magnifying glass ('spotlight search') and type 'terminal'
2. when the terminal opens, type `pip install pyenchant` and press return

If this is what happened, don't sweat it. I made the same mistake as a beginner, and I suspect many others have done the same.

Answer (score 0):

Also, do not enter the `$` not necessary.

make sure you use terminal

at command line enter:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

then run

`python get-pip.py`

Make sure you have pip installed correctly.

After try `pip install penchant`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by combining pieces of each answer :). Using Spotlight Search I was able to find terminal. I first used Jorge's URL to get pip, and tried to use

```
    python get-pip.py
```

but found that I needed to use

```
    python3 get-pip.py
```

instead. Then with

```
    python3 -m pip install pyenchant
```

I was able to get it to work. Thanks so much!